# Partitioning with the choice of records by combination of fields (sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

Please tell me how to write code in sql.
If in a given set (Table 1), provided that "clusterid" are the same and "is not null", and also provided that "issuedate" and "operdate" are the same. Lines with more unique "publid + inn" combinations are displayed. (table 2)

table 1
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|----|------|---------|----------|----------|
|333| --1--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|
|222| --1--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|
|333| --2--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|
|222| --2--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|
|111| --2--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|

table 2
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|----|------|---------|----------|----------|
|333| --2--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|
|222| --2--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|
|111| --2--|---12---|01-01-21|05-01-21|

It must be done through window functions, I tried, but the request does not work

```html
SELECT a.*
   FROM (SELECT m.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY clusterid order by issuedate desc, operdate desc, count(inn) desc) AS rn
          FROM table as m 
          GROUP BY publid
          WHERE clusterid is not null
          ) AS a
    WHERE a.rn = 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Select * from (
 Select *, rank() over (order by cnt desc) rn from (
  (Select publid, clusterid, issuedate, operdate, count(distinct 
  inn) as cnt
  From table where clusterid is not null 
  group by publid, clusterid, issuedate, operdate)
 )
) where rn =1;
```